# foundation 5 row side style

Tags: styles, row, zurb-foundation

I've seen several web pages using Foundation and one characteristic feature is the width of rows. The great thing of those pages is they had awesome styling in both sides of the web site.

So the issue is not how to modify rows width but how to target the sides of the rows in order to style them.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what do you mean by styling outside rows, if you want elements to not be contained on rows you could take them to external positioning by adding specific css classes and properties to a div, like

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="left-box-off-row" class="small-12 column">
  <!-- Content here -->
  </div>
</div> 
<style>
   #left-box-off-row{left:-20em;width:20em;}
</style>
```

This is just an example of making a div go outside of rows but keep their behaviour. Not including divs on rows also makes them position outside the grid. What elements do you want to style?

EDITION AFTER YOUR RESPONSE

My personal recommendation would be this, if you want your content to be included within the main grid use columns. Check foundation 5 documentation, but on short explaining, each row has 12 columns, so if you want to arrange content to fit on 70% main content and 30% something like a sidebar, I would do something like this.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <!-- Your left sidebar content -->
    </div>
    <div class="large-8 columns">
        <!-- Your main content -->
    </div>
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <!-- Your right sidebar content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The example above is one of the most easy and common layouts, a main content with a sidebar. As you can see, the columns count should add 12, so classes can be changed to large-10 and large-1, and by this way, you can set up additional classes to change div behaviour according to different screen sizes, its the beauty of using a framework.

This is very basic understanding of what foundation 5 is. It seems you are beginning and its ok,  but first I strongly recommend you check the documentation given here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/ , it includes explanation of all foundation 5 controls, specially the use of columns, which will help you accomplish lots of designs, that are responsive too, in just a matter of days. Good luck,

Comment: All I want is to have my main app within the rows' width. Suppose I set up a row width of 70%. So what I'd like to do, is to style the 15% left at each side, with photos, slides or whatever. Is that what your code does? Thank you very much for the reply!

Comment: No it just add divs for banners or that sort of things, you will have a lot of trouble by using rows width 70% if you want the remaining 30% to be adaptive to resolution and keep foundation grid. My recommendation will be on the next answer.

Comment: Yeah yours must be the answer. I might've got confused because of the amazingness of those sites, and cannot actually admit theyre where done with a simple grid use. Thanks for your response Jonathan!